# Add www to urls having HTTPS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

I need to add www to all the url which doesn't have the www at the starting(site is build in drupal). I have done the same for http request using the following code in htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Now I want to add the same for urls having https, like I need to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com.

I have tried several methods without any success. Please help me at the earliest as possible. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s (on:(s)|off:s)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I have tried your code but it is not working and I'm getting an ssl error. I have even tried anubhava's suggestion(below one) but that one is also not working.